# How can I create a folder for file templates in PhpStorm?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, file-templates

I use file templates in PhpStorm a lot. So in time I've got a big lists of file templates. Now PhpStorm limits this to an X number amount of file templates.

Is there a way that I can group these file templates in a folder or something? (like how PHPUnit test is nested in a PHPUnit folder)?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not possible (no built-in functionality) and I have found no plugin that would allow use to create such folders via GUI.

I guess (based on my searches) the best match would be this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-60214 and related -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

> Now PhpStorm limits this to an X number amount of file templates.

Have you tried speed search (start typing the name while popup with all templates is shown)? It may not show all templates as your list is too big ... but may be able to show them after filtering/searching (when list is shorter).